# Why ruby modulo is different from java/other lang ?

Tags: java, ruby, modulo

i am basically coming from java background and struggling to understand the modulo operation in Ruby.

```
(5 % 3)     
(-5 % 3)    
(5 % -3)    
(-5 % -3)
```

The above operation in Java yields,
    2
   -2
    2
   -2

But in Ruby, the same expression yields  2
1
-1
-2 .

How logically ruby is good  at this? How the module operation is implemented in Ruby ? If the same operation is defined as a web services, how both services can match the logic.

Comment: It looks like ruby is including 0 as number in its negative calculations.

Comment: I believe Java takes the remainder with the sign of the dividend, while Ruby takes the sign of the divisor. Have to check the specs...

Comment: It looks as though ruby tries to be different.. I'm also now learning it with background in other c-like languages and see a lot of questionable differences in operator/construct names. SCNR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, the result of the modulo operation has the same sign as the dividend.

In Ruby, it has the same sign as the divisor.  `remainder()` in Ruby has the same sign as the dividend.

You might also want to refer to [modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Answer (score 3):

The sign of the remainder changes from language to language. The "right" way to do it is up for debate...

Ruby implements both ways. The `remainder` function has the same behavior as Java, while `modulo` and the `%` operator use the other algorithm.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) has a list of programming languages and how they implement modulo.

Answer (score 3):

Because Ruby defines `x.modulo(y)` to be `x-y*(x/y).floor`.  See [ruby-doc.org](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Numeric.html#method-i-modulo)